# No puedo cambiar navbar-inverse en proyecto asp mvc

Tags: c#, css, bootstrap, mvc, asp

estoy empezando con el desarrollo en asp mvc, y me esta costando poder cambiar el color predeterminado del navbar de un proyecto. El color del mismo quedo de la siguiente manera
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al inspeccionar el código desde el navegador y cambiar el color de la propiedad ".navbar-inverse", puedo modificar el color, pero modificando desde el archivo bootstrap.css no consigo cambiarlo.

Espero que puedan ayudarme. Saludos!

Comment: Hola Ramiro, bienvenido, por favor muéstranos cómo estás intentando cambiar los valores en tu código. Te invito a leer ¿cómo crear un [example]?

Comment: no es recomendable que cambies el estilo modificando el bootstrap lo mejor es que agregues un estilo personalisado.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

bootstrap usa codigos de colores y a su vez declaran varias reglas tipo !important que le da prioridad por asi decirlo primaria y te impide cambiar de color, pero puedes ponerlo en tu header este script y con la misma regla el navegador te lo interpretara primero el color que le des, si no has probado cambiar de color de manera normal con este script te dara la prioridad(si tu clase es .navbar-inverse , ponla en vez de nav.navbar)

podrias probar con este codigo en tu header de html

```
  <style type="text/css">

    
nav.navbar {  /*Nombre de la clase, debes investigar como se llama la clase de tu navbar*/
  background-color: #90ed7d !important;   /*fondo del navbar*/
}

</style>
```